# Django: let users create sites with personalized urls

Tags: django, django-urls

I am using django and have urls such as the following in my url.py

```
url('^mysite/home/$', home),
url('^mysite/listings/$', listings),
```

Now, what I want is for users to be able to create their own accounts, which would then have their own url names. I'm thinking something like wordpress:

```
macks_knitting_blog.wordpress.com
```

However, the two following urls should both map to the same function, listings.

```
macks_knitting_blog.mysite.com/listings
my_trip.mysite.com/listings
```

The accounts are essentially identical and the same functions and templates will be used for all (unlike wordpress). The information that is shown will be filtered based on request.user and the template will look a bit different based on request.path.

Is it possible to do something like this? It would also be fine with:

```
mysite.com/macks_knitting_blog/listings
```

I've read about Django sites but it didn't seem to hold in this case. Or did I miss something? The idea is that I shouldn't need to change settings.py or url.py for this to happen. It should all happen automatically. Otherwise, I can just think of assigning some id to the new site and passing that around - not very personalized looking.

Comment: Incase you haven't looked at http://blog.uysrc.com/2011/03/23/serving-multiple-sites-with-django/

Comment: Seems like this may be exactly what I need! I'll read it and report back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an idea:
In your url section change the listings line to

```
url('^mysite/([^//]*)/listings/$', listings)
```

And your function in 'views.py' should look like this:

```
def listings(request, username):
    ...
    return HttpResponse(...)
```

username argument receives string segment between the slashes right after mysite and 'listings'
Hope that helps

Comment: Hey - it's so simple! I envision a decorator around each function to make sure the site exists and to sure the user matches the site.